# dnxcore50 not removable from targets

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget, xamarin.forms, .net-core

I have a problem with Xamarin.Forms when I want to create a new project. It always tells me that the PCL has the wrong targets to install xamarin.forms as there is no fitting library. I've checked that and come to the point that the `dnxcore50` target ruins the whole thing.

And now the Story of how i got that one:
At first I had an error while setting permissions on android with the properties window. It threw an error and wouldn't let me close it. I needed to kill it with the Task-Manager. After some searching I decided that I update the complete xamarin platform, VS2013 (which was on update 4 at that time) and NuGet and so on. After that I've tried again but nothing was different. So I've decided to try it with VS 2015. Deinstalling VS2013 and installing VS15. There i had to realize that VS15 and Windows 8.0 are incompatible to some point, as VS15 is unable to create or open up WinPhone 8.0 Projects and Win8 unable to handle WinPhone 8.1. Thanks Microsoft.
Okay, i thought, I still have VS12. So, after the 3rd time installing xamarin I was shown the error message I've described above. Well okay I thougth, maybe VS12 can't handle that. But after I reinstalled VS13 and Xamarin for the 4th time I came to realize that the installation of VS15 must've added this `dnxcore50` target and I'am unable to remove it from my system. I've deinstalled the .Net 4.6 Framework completely removed everything that sounded like that, but it still shows up in the targets. I even tried to play around with the PCL targets to get a working result, but either it wasn't compatible to the other projects, or the `dnxcore50` showed up.

Right now I'm in hell as I've tried for 2 days now to get VS and Xamarin back to normal. How can I remove this `dnxcore50` target from my system?

Edit:
Now I've uninstalled every NuGet package in the project and tried to install Xamarin.Forms:
[image]
after that I've looked at my targets of the PCL project:
[image]
Okay stackOverflow thinks here is code, so I'm filling up this area with some text so I can get 3 Pictures in here. I hope this one works. This definitly is a weird behaviour. BTT:
I've removed the Win8 target and tried to install Xamarin.Forms again
[image]
As you can see in both the dnxcore50 target which I cannot seem to un-target ruins it for me.

Comment: Please see my edit below

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, I just dealt with something similar myself. However I don't think ASP.NET Core is the issue. Here is my default Target setup for

[image: Change Targets]

You might have a dependency in that project that is causing the issue. Uninstall any other NuGet packages, reset your targets then try Xamarin.Forms as the first package to install.

You could also try changing the project type manually by editing the .proj file. Change your profile type to 78 as shown below.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>10.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile78</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: If you could go to my website xamarinhelp.com and get in contact with me and send through the project files (or at least a repro) I will take a look at it on my machine because Profile78 should certainly work. That way we can at least see if its a VS Config issue or a Proj issue.

Comment: From looking at your package as I mentioned in email, it worked fine for my on VS 2015 which means it is a VS configuration issue on your end, or a NuGet configuration issue. Will have to research further to find out a possible cause.

Comment: Try uninstalling ASP.NET 5 RC1 or beta (whatever you have) from VS2013 to see if that solves the issue

Comment: I've uninstalled the ASPN.NET and Web tools from VS2013 which came with the Update 5 and also searched for ASP.NET 5 in my registry, but nothing could be found. Also I've removed everything from the Programs and Features Window, that had ASP.NET in its name. It didn't work. Reinstalling VS also doesn't do a thing. ATM I'm making a Backup of this PC and plan to cleanly reinstall Windows. But I'm still looking for another way to get rid of this problem.